# (400) Bad request if I change "localhost" to "192.168.3.3" in URL to Web API

Tags: web-services, localhost, asp.net-web-api

I run Web API project from Visual Studio 2013.
It works:

> `https://localhost:44300/api/test/token/?username=T1@mail.com&password=T1@mail.com`

But it returns "Bad request" response:

> `https://192.168.3.3:44300/api/test/token/?username=T1@mail.com&password=T1@mail.com`

Why?

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the `/` before the `?`, e.g. `.../token?username=...`. If it works with locahost it should still work with an IP address, but just giving ideas.

It could be something to do with HTTPS. Since you've effectively changed the IP address of your service, you may have to readjust the SSL/certificate settings or generate another certificate to target the new IP address. Before doing all this, the first thing I'd try is to temporarily disable HTTPS and just go over normal HTTP for testing.

If the above doesn't solve it or give any clues, then I'd also investigate the possibility of having to enable [CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). Even if that was the problem, you'd probably be getting a different error, so it's a long shot, but it's relatively simple to set up and *just might* help.

I can't think of anything else right now that might be causing your issue.

Comment: I'll try later these steps. Thanks.